# Set the WScript session title from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

In the batch file:

```
TASKLIST /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted*" | FINDSTR wscript.exe || START "TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted" WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "SoundFont setted." 0
TASKLIST /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted*" | FINDSTR wscript.exe || START "TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted" WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "SoundFont setted." 0
TASKLIST /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted*" | FINDSTR wscript.exe || START "TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted" WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "SoundFont setted." 0
```

In the VBScript file:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 2 Then
    Message = Replace(WScript.Arguments(0), "\n", vbNewLine)
    WScript.Quit MsgBox(Message, WScript.Arguments(1))
End If
```

Instead of going out only one message box, three come out. Why?

Edit: This question is a NOT duplicate because my question is: "Change WScript Title with Console" and not "Change Console Title with vbscript".

Comment: Have you tried using the `/V` option and perhaps parentheses, `(TaskList /V | FindStr /IC:"TiMidity++ - SoundFont setted*")>Nul 2>&1||Start ...`?

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: Perhaps a _timing_ problem... When the `tasklist` command is executed the second and third time the first instance of the new task is not registered yet.

Comment: Also, I'd consider trying to reduce the string for `FindStr` to match, to something shorter, if it's unlikely that other windows would contain the same string.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your batch file calls the VBScript three times, so why wouldn't it output the `Msgbox()` three times??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Console Title with vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3037275/608639)

Comment: Not instead! Because my question is: "Change WScript Title with Console" and not "Change Console Title with vbscript".

Comment: Possible duplicate, not certain.